# Inherit from an abstract class and realize an interface at the same time

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I have C# class definition

```
MyViewModelClass: INotifyPropertyChanged, MyAbstractBaseForVMClass
```

It won't compile. Gives and error at the start of MyAbstractBaseForVMClass literal:

Interface definition is expected.

Can I not realize an interface, and inherit from an abstract class at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can. Just reverse them.

```
MyViewModelClass: MyAbstractBaseForVMClass, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Interfaces always come after classes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know logical explanation to this limitation?

Comment: Here is another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675580/why-must-the-base-class-be-specified-before-interfaces-when-declaring-a-derived-c

Comment: My guess is, because there is no multiple inheritance besides interfaces, the first must be the base or abstract class and after that follows the interfaces, which can be of course more than one.

Comment: I didn't know that there was such a limitation, therefor was unable to find that question by name. Thanks.